# Add error messages returned from server with Parsley JS

Tags: javascript, laravel, parsley.js

I have setup form and parsleyjs. I am using Laravel 5.1 and when I submit invalid data, my FormRequest returns 422. I would like to iterate trough errors returned by Laravel and add them manually to form.

I can do it like this:

```
var error = errorsBag.username[0];
$("#username").parsley().addError("remote", {message: error});
```

And this adds error message to the form. But it sticks around, It doesn't go awayif I change field value but field does change color to green. (I am using .has-success for valid fields).

How can I make errors go away as soon as field changes its value, despite creating OnChange EventListener.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your own custom validator; it can return a custom error message that you could build from your responses.